# Why is the class DOMText returned for childrens after a DOMNodeList iteration?

Tags: php, dom

```
$html = 'foo blah <a href="">foo bar</a> blah <a href="">foo</a> blah foo';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()');
echo get_class($nodes);
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo '<br />';
    echo get_class($node) . ':'; //look here
    echo $node->wholeText;
}
```

Why is the class type DOMText for each $node ?

Comment: It is not. You are using `$node` not `$nodes` in the iteration.

Comment: @fire.. I edited the question to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is asking for text nodes with `//text()`. :)

DOMText is a specialized DOMNode, which in its turn is the base object for just about every DOM related object (except DOMXPath, I believe, which makes sense)

The object hierarchy for DOMText is actually as followed;

```
DomNode  
 - DOMCharacterData
   - DomText
```

You can learn more about this by examining [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php)